# How to count children from different lists? [jQuery]

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to count the number of child elements a certain category has.

This is the situation:

```
<ul id="select_cat">
  <li id="_1">Category 1 (<span>#</span>)</li>
  <li id="_2">Category 2 (<span>#</span>)</li>
</ul>

<ul id="cat_1>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="cat_2">
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
</ul>
```

So I want to count the number of children a category has.
In this example the first cardinal sign should be 3, and the second should be 2.

How can I do this, using jQuery.

[Check an example (not jQuery)](http://www.jopwijk.be/links)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#select_cat li').each(function() {
 $('span', this).text($('#cat' + this.id).children().length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
$("#cat_2").children("li").length
```

I have a feeling the question wants to ask something more.
Anyway, it's just wiring it up to some heuristic. E.g. iterate over the "select_cat" elements with `each` and use their ID/position/name to count the elements in a category above and then use a `text` on the span (isolated with `find/child`), etc.

My two cents: I'd make the server do it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but that's not what I'm looking for.
With your solution, I'll have to add a line of code each time I add a category.

There should be a way to count the children of every category,
but I'm not sure how to accomplish this..

Probably with a while loop, to count the number of <ul>'s with an ID  cat_X..

Comment: Yep, something like that is exactly what I need, just don't know how to do this. Could you give me a hand please? I never was any good with loops. A shame, I know..

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of this:

```
alert($("#cat_1").children("li").length);
alert($("#cat_1").children("li").size());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#select_cat li").each(function(){
    $("span", this).html(
      $("#cat" + $(this).attr('id')).children().size();
    );
  });
```

Comment: So you're saying that this.id is less efficient than $(this).attr('id') ?

Comment: FYI, it’s more efficient to (1) just use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`, (2) set `.text()` instead of `.html()`, and (3) read `.length` instead of calling the `.size()`  method (resulting in an extra function call).